# Try to insert template html to node-mailer but get error "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open"

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I use node-mailer and it work fine and now i try to add template html but always got error when i try to open the external html file.

This is my old code with inline html and it work perfect!

```
const sendSwitchBetweenStages = (flowID, flow, stageID, userName) => {
    const message = {
        to: userEmail(flow, stageID),
        subject: titleMessage(stageID),
        text: '',
        html: `
            <div dir="rtl">
              <h1> test </h1>
            </div>
          `
    };
    return emailerService.sendMail(message);
};
```

Now I try to add a external template :

```
const sendSwitchBetweenStages = (flowID, flow, stageID, userName) => {
  const template = fs.readFileSync('./index.html',{ encoding:'utf-8' });
    const message = {
        to: userEmail(flow, stageID),
        subject: titleMessage(stageID),
        text: '',
        html: template
    };
    return emailerService.sendMail(message);
};
```

error : `Error: Uncaught (in promise): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'index.html'`

The index.html it on the same root and i don't know what the problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give fs.readFileSync an absolute and not relative path.

As an example:

```
fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'release.hbs')).toString('utf8')
```

So you should try or something like that:

```
fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),{ encoding:'utf-8' });
```

btw you should look into [handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars). it is really good for template creation. I use this combination of nodemailer and handelbars in a current project of mine. Works perfectly fine.